# How can I specify stream priority while sending http2 requests messages in golang?

Tags: go, http2

For the client example below, before calling "client.Get()", there is no option to provide the stream priority ?

Do we have any option to specify stream priority ?

```
client := http.Client{

        Transport: &http2.Transport{

            DialTLS: func(network, addr string, cfg *tls.Config) (net.Conn, error) {

                return net.DialTimeout(network, addr, time.Second)

            },

                AllowHTTP: true,

        },

    }


// can I specify http2 stream priority before calling Get() below ??

    resp, err := client.Get(path)
```

Comment: From the `net/http` documentation: _"To enable HTTP/2 for more complex configurations, to use lower-level HTTP/2 features, or to use a newer version of Go's http2 package, import "golang.org/x/net/http2" directly and use its ConfigureTransport and/or ConfigureServer functions"_

Comment: The question is not about how to enable http2 !

My question was specifically about http2 stream enabled connections. How can we specify stream priority (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-5.3) in the golang implementation.

Comment: The quoted docs state _"to use lower-level HTTP/2 features"_, I would consider steam priority a "lower level feature", which requires directly using the `golang.org/x/net/http2` package. You cannot access that from the std library `net/http` package.